# Swift Delegate in own class

Tags: ios, swift, textkit

I am currently trying to write my first Swift Mac application. Currently I have hard times refactoring some code into another class.

Current Status:

```
import Cocoa

class TestClass: NSObject, NSTextStorageDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var codeTextView: NSTextView!
    var syntaxParser:TRexSyntaxKitParser?
    var textStorage : NSTextStorage!
    init(syntaxParser:TRexSyntaxKitParser, textView:NSTextView) {
        self.syntaxParser = syntaxParser

        super.init()

        if let textViewStorage = textView.textStorage {
            self.textStorage = textViewStorage
            self.textStorage.delegate = self
        }
    }

    func textStorageDidProcessEditing(notification: NSNotification) {
        let inputString = self.textStorage.string
        let wholeRange = NSMakeRange(0, count(inputString))

        self.textStorage.removeAttribute(NSForegroundColorAttributeName, range:wholeRange)

        let attributes = self.syntaxParser!.parse(inputString)
        print("Attributes: \(attributes)")

        for attribDict: [String:AnyObject] in attributes {

            let range = NSMakeRange(attribDict["rangeStart"] as! Int, attribDict["rangeLength"] as! Int)
            self.textStorage.addAttribute(attribDict["attributeKey"] as! String, value:NSColor(hexString: attribDict["color"] as! String)!, range:range)
        }
    }
}
```

and this is how i call this class:

```
import Cocoa

class CodeEditorViewController: NSViewController {

    @IBOutlet var codeTextView: NSTextView!
    var syntaxParser:TRexSyntaxKitParser?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.syntaxParser = TRexSyntaxKitParser(language:"latex",theme:"classic")
        let testClass = TestClass(syntaxParser: self.syntaxParser!, textView: self.codeTextView)
        codeTextView.lnv_setUpLineNumberView()
    }
```

but this produces the following error:

```
[NSFont textStorageDidProcessEditing:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

I do not see where I would call the delegate method from NSFont ? 
**So to be precise: How can I refactor the first class into two different one ?**

Comment: "this produces" _What_ produces it? You have not shown any evidence that you ever create a TestClass instance. But how you do that is crucial. Show it. Show your current refactored code (the old code is of no interest at all; you can actually delete that from the question if you like).

Comment: By the way, just to skip ahead to the punch line, you have a memory management mistake. What's happening is you're setting a delegate that is then going out of existence. We need to figure out why. You can work out exactly when this is happening by turning on Zombies.

Comment: Ok thanks I edited my answer according to your comment. I'll have a look at the NSZombies in Instruments.

Comment: That looks much better, thanks for that rewrite. The answer to the problem is now obvious to me! I'll write you a quick answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Think about the memory management of this line:

```
let testClass = TestClass(syntaxParser: self.syntaxParser!, textView: self.codeTextView)
```

`testClass` is a *local variable*. So what happens to your brand new TestClass instance? It comes into existence *and immediately vanishes in a puff of smoke* when `viewDidLoad` comes to an end.

Thus, you now have a delegate pointing at an object that does not exist. Hence, the crash.

Solution: make `testClass` something that will *persist* long enough to do you some good - like, an instance property of your view controller. That will give you exactly the refactoring you are after (this is a standard design pattern).